# How to Create a List of Vectors Using the Curve Class Traveling from A to B?

Tags: vb.net, monogame, curve

I'm trying to create a path for an object to travel by.

I want the path to use a curve that goes upwards from the start(A) to then fall down to the bottom(B).

Like this :

### [image: Travel Path]

I've looked at different ways to create a curved path and they all either use the Spritebatch to create the curve or don't use the Curve class. I need to create many curves in parallel to be used by many different sprites with each their own curve.

So i looked at the Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Curve class but i can't find any good resource for how to use it correctly.

The Curve class uses CurveKey for its points but it's unclear exactly how you convert a Key to a Vector2D as a key is defined in a Single numeric value and not a XY coordinate.

I want a SortedList of all the points that are needed for a Sprite to travel with the Curve that i can use with the Vector2D class but again, i don't really understand how to use the Curve class, [and the documentation is rather confusing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/silverlight/dotnet-windows-silverlight/bb196070(v%3Dxnagamestudio.35)).
It talks about that if you want more dimensions you can use multiple Curve objects but there isn't an example on there.

[I have not been able to get the CurveEditor to compile either](https://github.com/SimonDarksideJ/XNAGameStudio/wiki/Curve-Editor) and support for it seems to be long dead.

If anyone could show me how to make a curve with the Curve class and have that translate into a coordinate with Vector2D that would be a great starting point.

Comment: Your question is a mathematical and not an programming problem. You don't need any XNA Classes for this. Check Google for "Bezier Curves". That is probably what you are looking for. 
The calculation itself can be done with the standard Math class

Comment: @Pavel Slesinger I am aware of that but i might aswell learn and use the built-in functionality, when it's there.

Answer (score 1):

The `Vector2` class has a static method defined as:

`public static Vector2 Hermite(Vector2 value1, Vector2 tangent1, Vector2 value2, Vector2 tangent2, float amount)`

This is similar to a lerp, where the amount is a number between 0 and 1.